# Put new component inside existent composition

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, composite-component

I'm new in Java Web, and I'm just learning english...
I have multiples composite component, that works fine, like, for example, this code

```
<composite:interface>
   <composite:attribute name="usernameValue" />
</composite:interface>
<composite:implementation>

<h:form>
   <h:outputText id="username" value="#{cc.attrs.usernameValue}" />
</h:form>
```

When I need to use this component, I just do:

```
<myComposite:myComponent usernameValue="My user name value"/>
```

this works ok.

But, how to do if I need put more components inside this previously created component, like:

```
<h:form>
    <h:outputText id="username" value="My text 1" />
    <p:commandButton value="New button 2"/>
    <p:commandButton value="New button 3"/>
    <p:commandButton value="New button 4"/>
<h:form/>
```

Is there any way to do something like:

```
<myComposite:myComponent usernameValue="This will render default inside composite output text">
    <p:commandButton value="New button 1 to render inside my composite"/>
    <p:commandButton value="New button 2 to render inside my composite"/>
    <p:commandButton value="New button 3 to render inside my composite"/>
<myComposite:myComponent/>
```

I'm learning, and this time I recreate all composite that I need to use with attribute `render="true or false"` according the components that I will use, but this is like XGH.

Sorry for my english, I know that i need to improve it...

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, what your trying to achieve is what the tag [insertChildren](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/cc/insertChildren.html) does.

In your example, it would be like:

```
<composite:implementation>
   <h:form>
      <h:outputText id="username" value="#{cc.attrs.usernameValue}" />
      <composite:insertChildren />
   </h:form>
</composite:implementation>
```

and then use the component like you intended:

```
<myComposite:myComponent usernameValue="This will render default inside composite output text">
    <p:commandButton value="New button 1 to render inside my composite"/>
    <p:commandButton value="New button 2 to render inside my composite"/>
    <p:commandButton value="New button 3 to render inside my composite"/>
<myComposite:myComponent/>
```

And the commandButtons will be placed where the `insertChildren` tag was defined.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377542/jsf2-composite-components-are-cc-childcount-and-compositeinsertchildren) is another example of its usage.

Comment: Thanks... Worked like I need.

Comment: Haaa, como essa sua resposta me ajudou nos 5 últimos anos... Passando aqui só pra agradecer demais, essa foi uma das melhores aprendizagens que tive aqui.

Comment: Wow, you don't know how your answer helped me in the last 5 years ... I'm here just to thank you too much, this was one of the first and best lessons I had here...